# How to fix the black gradient on the top bar when windows are maximixed?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell, window, top-bar

I installed the Zorin OS theme on my gnome-shell. When I maximie any window the top bar transitions into a off putting white-black gradient color which I do not desire. A semi transperent top bar which matches with the theme appears only when the the applications are minimized. I have included screenshots.

[image: Top bar when windows are minimized]

[image: Top bar when windows are maximized]

How do I make the top bar same as it is while minimized on maximized windows as well?

Comment: https://github.com/ZorinOS/zorin-desktop-themes.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trail and errors found this code is required to add at the bottom of your Zorions gnome-shell theme file `gnome-shell.css`..

```
/* panel color */
#panel.solid {
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-gradient-end: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

the rgba color I have got from the text entry `/* TOP BAR */` with in the gnome-shell file. You can change what ever color you want..

```
/* TOP BAR */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* transition from solid to transparent */
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2em;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  box-shadow: none; }
```

[image]

[image]

---

My Customizations for windows normal and maximized..

[image]

Comment: I really thank you for your effort. It worked like a charm